# Schedule messages using Kafka

Tags: java, node.js, apache-kafka

I have recently started exploring Kafka. I have some timer tasks that need to be triggered after the timer expires. My use case is to schedule these timers as messages, at the moment I am using AMQ for scheduling messages using the AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY property provided to schedule messages. Additionally, AMQ is also being used for other message transfers.

As I intend to replace AMQ with Kafka, I am trying to figure out if there is a way I can achieve the message scheduling part with Kafka.

My application components are in Java and Node. Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you read documentation. This "question" is not a good fit for SO if you're just beginning and haven't done your research yet.

Comment: Hello Kayaman,

I believe my post gives the impression that I have not done enough research, I have read the documentation thoroughly but could not find anything related to scheduling messages. Therefore I tried asking it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use a setTimeout / Timer / ExecutorServive to schedule any code, as you'd do with any other library.

Kafka does not schedule data on its own